# Unable to connect to an API running on localhost using React Native

Tags: react-native, api, networking, expo

This is my first post so apologies if the format is wrong or I'm missing info or something!

I'm unable to connect to an API running on localhost through an Android emulator, or on a physical iPhone using React Native.

I've tried to change the localhost in my fetch request so it now looks as follows:
 `https://MYIPADDRESS:44357/api/user/login`

This is the error I get when trying to fetch the API

```
    TypeError: Network request failed
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
    - node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
    - node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:9:32 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
    - node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
    - node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
    - node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
    - node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
    - node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
    - node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
    - node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
    - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
    * [native code]:null in flushedQueue
    * [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

```
        fetch('https://IPADDRESS:44357/api/user/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                user: this.state.username,
                password: this.state.password,
            })
        })
```

I hope someone can help! :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide the API call code

Answer (score 0):

On Android Emulator, you should use http://127.0.0.1:44357.
On iOS Simulator, you should use http://10.0.2.2:44357.
On real devices, you should open 44357 port and use http://YOURIPADDRESS:44357.

Comment: This hasn't worked unfortunately. I tried on an Android Emulator with url https://127.0.0.1:4435.